# Import symbol from another module locally into a class

Tags: python, python-import

How can I import a symbol from a module locally into a class?

**B.py**

```
def bar():
    print("bar")
```

**main.py**

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        from B import bar

    def foo(self):
        bar()  # <-- Want to call the function here

a = A()
a.foo() # <-- This should not give a NameError
bar()   # <-- This should give a NameError
```

**Output**:

```
$ python main.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "[...]/main.py", line 11, in <module>
    a.foo()
  File "[...]/main.py", line 8, in foo
    bar()
NameError: name 'bar' is not defined
```

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Is the import expensive, or are you just trying to keep things clean?

Comment: @2e0byo I am trying to isolate scope yes! To make it more maintainable.

Comment: In that case I think this is probably an antipattern.  Just use a leading underscore to signal that one shouldn't import bar from your module.

Comment: This q has been closed so I can't answer it, but there *is* a way to do what I think you're asking for: move the import to *before* the `__init__` and then use `self.bar()`.  This way it will be evaluated on loading but scope limited to the class.  However I have never seen this in the wild.

Comment: I think I've missed the point of the question; I've reopened it and pointed out more clearly what the issue is.

Comment: And that can't work as is. If `bar` isn't global nor local to `foo`, then just `bar()` can't work. You'll need to write at least `self.bar()` and assign `bar` to be an attribute. Or `import` `bar` inside `foo`.

Comment: @2e0byo Thanks for your comments..The question has been reopened.

Answer (score 2):

You *can* import into class scope:

```py
class A:
    from B import bar
    def foo(self):
        self.bar()

A().foo()
```

**edit**: note that if bar does not want to recieve self, you need to make it a staticmethod:

```py
class A:
    from B import bar
    bar = staticmethod(bar)

    def foo(self):
        self.bar()
```

Does that look hacky to you? It certainly does to me.  At a first glance, it looks like we're trying to add methods to a class without using inheritance.  More naturally we would do something like this:

```py
# b.py
def foo():
    return 7

class FooMixin:
    @staticmethod # or not, depending on what you're doing
    def bar():
        return foo()

# a.py
from b import FooMixin

class A(FooMixin):
    def baz(self):
        print("bar() returned", self.bar()")
```

This is really a different paradigm entirely---building up functionality by multiple inheritance with mixins.

Of course, `A.bar` exists as soon as the class definition is evaluated, and is shared between classes, exactly the same way as anything else defined at class scope.

Note however that I have never seen this and am struggling to think of a use case.  Normally one would just do this, as @donkopotamus notes:

```py
from B import bar as _local_bar

class A:
    def foo(self):
        _local_bar()
```

Since variables beginning with a leading underscore have module scope, encapsultion is achieved, i.e. this will fail:

```py
from foo import A # success
from foo import _local_bar # failure
```

Which is probably all you want in this case.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying! I would like to avoid using the longer form `self.bar()`. What modifications do I need to do to just use `bar()` ?

Comment: I also get an error when using `self.bar()` : *"TypeError: bar() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given"*

Comment: @HåkonHægland for the shorter form: you can't.  Python namespaces don't work like that: if you want to access something which lives in the class from a method, you have to refer explicitly to self.  Thus you probably want to import into the *module* and use the leading underscore to prevent importing later; or import in every method which needs `B.bar`, although if there are a few that gets tiresome quickly.  (This repeated importing *is* seen, but usually only when importing is expensive and the method may never be called, since it defers the import to the first run.)

Comment: Thanks again, I have an appointment right now so I do not have time to consider. But  I'll come back later..

Comment: @HåkonHægland see my edit for your other question.  I don't think I'm going to add much to this answer as I think the real answer is 'don't do this', *unless* you're trying to do something like building mixins---in which case take advantage of python's multiple inheritence and just define mixins for the methods you want, which will neatly encapsulate everything (when doing OOP I do this all time, and it's quite a common pattern).  If you're just trying to get python classes to be a bit more like e.g. c++... sorry, can't be done, you need explicit `self`.

Answer (score 1):

Import the name in the local scope of `A.foo`

```
class A:
    def foo(self):
        from B import bar
        bar()
```

Then `A().foo()` will call `bar()` and `bar` will **not** be visible in the global scope.

Comment: Is it possible to make it local to class `A`, not just `A.foo()` ?

Comment: Not in the sense you are probably intending, no.  Why not import it globally, possibly aliased, as eg `from B import bar as _hidden_bar`?